# How to stop viewport width of a label from stretching after a certain browser size

Tags: css

I made a small website where width of certain elements are given in vw. It looked all good in my laptop. But when viewed in a 1920 screen, I could see the content is over stretched. I want to know if there is a way to stop viewport width and viewport paddings I have used in my website to stop stretching the elements after a while.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting `max-width: value` to your container in you css file

Also to set diverent styles after certain screen width you can yuse media query

```
@media(min-width: 1000px){
   //your style
}
```

Comment: Even after putting max width my elements get stretched. The container becomes left aligned. And I can see the body colour I used on the side of the screen. Container ends at 1020 but the contents continue to stretch past it